# Change key code for a given device

Tags: systemd, keyboard, udev

I just have get a Logitech Spotlight Presenter, it has two buttons which have key codes incompatible with my presentation (revealjs).
`Next` and `Previous` are binded as `Right` and `Left`, while I want to change them to `n` and `p`.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and ArchLinux.

The parameter of the device:

```
$ lsusb -d 046d:c53e -v

Bus 001 Device 012: ID 046d:c53e Logitech, Inc.
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        32
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc53e
  bcdDevice           41.00
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           84
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      59
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     148
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               2
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      98
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               2
```

Here are the current show keys:

```
# showkeys --scancodes
0xe0 0x4d 0xe0 0xcd
0xe0 0x4b 0xe0 0xcb

# showkeys --keycodes
keycode 106 release
keycode 105 release
```

Here are the show keys according of my keyboard:

```
# showkeys --scancodes
0x31 0xb1
p0x19 0x99

# showkeys --keycodes
keycode  49 release
keycode  25 release
```

I have deduced the following `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/61-logitech-spotlight-presenter-revealjs.hwdb`:

```
# This file has been created to improve Logitech Spotlight Presenter in revealjs
evdev:input:b*v046dpc53e*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_69=p
 KEYBOARD_KEY_6a=n
```

I have then tried the following

```
$ sudo systemd-hwdb update
$ udevadm trigger
$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

But my remote still fires `Right`/`Left`.

Comment: In my notes I have that the vendor/product hex codes have to be in uppercase, `b*v046DpC53E*`. Might be worth trying.

Comment: Nice try, sadly it changed nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open source software *Projecteur* allows you to map
the buttons of the Logitech Spotlight (and have a customizable desktop spot)

Project Homepage: https://github.com/jahnf/Projecteur

Packages for arch are also available:
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/projecteur

For Ubuntu, packages are available on the project's github page as well
as in the Ubuntu repositories 20.10 and later.

Disclaimer: I am the author of *Projecteur*